# How can you validate the first column of a JTable with regex?

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, inputverifier

I'm making a program, and I have to validate whether the first column is an IP-Address or not.

So far, I have only figured out how to find how to filter a row. But it is the column that has to be checked before I write the data to a file.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: *"But I only find how to filter a row."*  Link to that.  Once that is done, all you need to do is offer a control to the user to edit the IP column of that row.

Answer (score 8):

You can use an [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) to verify the input of the table cell. That way you don't have to verify everything *after* all the inputs are in, which may be a hassle if there are many incorrect inputs. With the `InputVerifier` You will get validation per cell input.

Here is an example. I'm not sure if the regex is correct for IP address, but I have a final static field you can change to a regex that *does* work if this one doesn't.

With this particular `InputVerifier`, if the field it matches the regex oor if the field is empty, it will allow focus change, if not you will get an error dialog.

```
text.matches(IP_REGEX) || text.isEmpty();
```

[image]

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class TableVerifyInput {

    private static final String IP_REGEX = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$";

    public TableVerifyInput() {
        final InputVerifier verifier = getInputVerifier();
        final DefaultCellEditor editor = getTableCellEditor(verifier);

        String[] cols = {"IP address", "Column 2"};
        Object[][] data = {{null, null}, {null, null}};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);

        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 0) {
                    return editor;
                } else {
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
                }
            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Cell Verify");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private InputVerifier getInputVerifier() {
        InputVerifier verifier = new InputVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
                JTextField field = (JTextField) input;
                String text = field.getText();
                return text.matches(IP_REGEX) || text.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
                boolean valid = verify(input);
                if (!valid) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid IP address");
                }
                return valid;
            }

        };
        return verifier;
    }

    private DefaultCellEditor getTableCellEditor(final InputVerifier verifier) {
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()) {
            {
                getComponent().setInputVerifier(verifier);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean stopCellEditing() {
                if (!verifier.shouldYieldFocus(getComponent())) {
                    return false;
                }
                return super.stopCellEditing();
            }

            @Override
            public JTextField getComponent() {
                return (JTextField) super.getComponent();
            }

        };
        return editor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableVerifyInput();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve the column data and apply an regular expression on it to check for a valid IP:

```
    String regex = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$";

    String ip = (String)table.getValueAt(row, column);

    boolean isValidIP = ip.matches(regex);
```