# Using DefaultTableCellRenderer to specify column class in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to use the DefaultTableCellRenderer to format a column in JTable.  For example: if user enter:

```
20140914
```

It will be format as:

```
2014-09-14
```

My code are following:

```
    //Setting data type for each class
    //This is a method within the DefaultTableModel
    public Class getColumnClass(int col)
    {

        if (col == 0)
            return DateRenderer.class;
        if (col == 1 || col == 2)
            return String.class;
        else 
            return Double.class;


    }

//This is a separate class that I have problem with:
static class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{

    //Using Decimal format to format dash
    DecimalFormatSymbols fmtSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    fmtSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('-');
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("####.##.##");


    public DateRenderer() {
        super(); }

    public void setValue(Object value)
    {

        setText (fmt.format(value));

    }

}
```

There's two problem with the code.  One is that I have problem with the line:

```
 fmtSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('-');
```

Another is that it will make my whole column become un-editable (Other column can still be edited and saved).

Comment: Is the data being entered by the use from the actual table, or from like a text field or something?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KRVMA.png  This is an image of my GUI interface.  What I want is that: if the user enter the date under the date column, it will automatically adding '-' (dash) between the numbers.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What happens when the user enters something besides the format `yyyyMMdd`? How will you handle _that_?

Comment: well, this is only a simple program that design to handle yyyyMMdd at the moment.  I want to take one step at a time and to understand how to program and format the date before I move on into the next step(handling the "error" part of user entering the wrong number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "well, this is only a simple program that design to handle yyyyMMdd at the moment. I want to take one step at a time and to understand how to program and format the date"

- As for the format, you shouldn't be using a `DecimalFormat`. Instead use a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). A commonly used subclass is [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- As for your current implementation of `DefautTableCellRenderer`, you are missing a key component, which is the overriding of `getTableCellRendererComponent`. You can see [How to use Renders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for a proper way. Also there are [may questions](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr&ei=YJFxU8W9Apbp8AXz7oKAAg#q=site:stackoverflow.com+defaulttablecellrenderer+date) you can look at.
- As for your overriding of `getColumnClass()`, the column class shoun't be the renderer component. You couln't instead make the column class `Date` and have the default renderer for `Date` do the rendering for you. You can see more at [Using Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). If you don't want to it be `Date` and keep it as `String`, then the renderer should handle the re-rendering to the correct format.
- As for other options to handle the entering of invalid input:

  - You can look into using an [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) for the editing component for the cell. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018090/2587435) and also [many questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=stieg%20larsson#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20inputverifier).
  - You may even want to look into using some kind of date picker component for the editor of the cell. You can see many related [questions here](https://www.google.com/search?q=stieg%20larsson#q=site:stackoverflow.com+date+picker+for+jtable)
  - You may want to use a `JSpinner` for the editor. See [many questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20spinner%20for%20jtable%20cell)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a DecimalFormat to render the Date. Instead you should be using a `SimpleDataFormat`. See [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for a renderer that you can use.

> Another is that it will make my whole column become un-editable

A renderer does NOT control if a column is editable or not. The is the job of the `isCellEditable(...)` method.

Also, your `getColumnClass(...)` implementation is wrong. You should not be returning DateRender.class. Instead you should be returning the class of the data stored in the column, which should probably be `Date.class`.